# Get Dropdown Selected Value in Datalist ItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am using Dropdown list inside datalist. Now, I want dropdown selected value onDatalistItemBound.

How to get it ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ItemDataBound handler should look like :

```
protected void dl_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var myDropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("YourDropDownListID") as DropDownList;
        int currentItemID = int.Parse(this.dl.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString());

        myDropDownList.DataSource = GetDDLDataSource(currentItemID);
        myDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to bind dropdown, but I want dropdown SelectedValue. How to get it ???

Comment: you have to bind the that value somewhere in your datalist in label and make the `Visible = false` for that labe then found that label in same itemdatabound event where your are binding the drop-down and assign drop-down.selectedvalue after binding.

Comment: Thanks for information, I am using it through hiddelfield. But I want all nested dropdown selected value which are inside datalist. So how it is possible to get selected value of each dropdown and that is onItemDataBound ?

Comment: OnItemDatabound is fore for each row bounded in datalist..don't worry. You just write the code for one dropdown it will do the rest. Also don't forget to mark it as a answer.